# Subsetting everything but a given line in 1 column

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I have 4 different treatments. One of these treatments is the control group. I want to subset the data between control and other treatments.

I wrote this in R Studio:

```
ControlQ2<-subset(Q2, Treatment == "No_Suite")
```

Now how to select all the treatments except "No_Suite"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you well, but what about this one?

```
ExceptControlQ2<-subset(Q2, Treatment != "No_Suite")
```

If this is not what you were looking for, please provide an example with an expected output.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for!.. Thanks